# How to configure two schemes for Facebook custom tabs in android?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, intentfilter, android-facebook

I have two different app ids for Facebook in the same Android App let's say 
facebook_app_id_for_country1 = 12344454355435 
(app name is Android app for country 1), and
facebook_app_id_for_country2 = 32543545454554 
(app name is Android app for country 2).

now I need to have the proper naming while asking the user to authorise my app using Facebook account here is the custom tab activity:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme_country_1" />
        <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme_country_2" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two countries, you can personalise that into the Facebook developers app.

Comment: I just have to have different id for a specific country for legal reasons